# Converse to Inverse Function Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

A fairly general form of the Inverse Function Theorem is:

Suppose $X, Y$ are Banach spaces, $U \subset X$ is open and $f:U \to Y$ is continuously differentiable. If for some $x \in U$ the derivative $Df(x)$ is invertible, then there exists a neighborhood $V \subset f(U)$ such that $f(x) \in V$ and a continuously differentiable function $g: V \to U$ such that $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x \in V$.

A question I have had is whether there are any sufficient conditions such that the converse holds, i.e., if $Df(x)$ is not invertible then $f$ is locally not invertible.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(x)=x^3$ is not a counterexample, because $f$ is not a diffeomorphism around $0$. Any diffeomorphism has nonvanishing derivative, by the inverse function theorem. Your "in other words" sentence has a different meaning from the preceding one.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Thanks I see, because $x^{1/3}$ is not continuously differentiable. I will edit this "in other words" out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to phrase the question in the positive way: Suppose that $f:U\to V$ is invertible and $C^1$ smooth. Under what additional assumptions can we conclude that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, equivalently, that $Df$ is always invertible?

Results of this kind do exist, but only in finite dimensions as far as I know, and in low dimension at that. Way back in 1936 H. Lewy proved that in two dimensions every harmonic homeomorphism is a diffeomorphism (harmonicity of $f=(f_1,f_2)$ means that $\Delta f_1=\Delta f_2=0$, i.e., the components are harmonic functions). There are generalizations to other elliptic PDE in two dimensions, but unfortunately everything seems to fall apart in higher dimensions. This [talk](http://www.dmi.units.it/~alessang/divulg/slides/2009Purdue.pdf) by G. Alessandrini gives an overview of this subject.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to require that the inverse function $g$ be surjective. Suppose there exists a neighborhood $V\subset f(U)$ such that $f(x)\in V$ and a *surjective* continuously differentiable function $g:V\to U$ such that $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in V$. Then for any $x\in U$ we have some $y\in V$ such that $g(y)=x$, so by Chain Rule
$$\begin{align} I &= D_y\:\mathrm{Id}\\
&=D_{y}(f\circ g)\\
&=D_{x}f\circ D_yg
\end{align}$$
thus $D_xf$ is invertible.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is true for arbitrary (finite) dimension, so how does that tie in with what @user31373 says in their answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Item **2** below may follow the intention of the question most closely, depending on what kind of ``invertibility'' was intended.

**1.**

The way you pose the question we have to do with local **right** inverse of the function, but simultaneously you ask about invertibility of the linear map, which to me seems to be defined as having an inverse element (which is both left and right inverse, see the second paragraph in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element)).

Thus the function $f(x,y) = x$ is a solution. $g(x)=(x,0)$ is the required right inverse,
and $Df(0)$ is trivially not invertible. (No 2x1 matrix is invertible.)

To get rid of the dimension inequality, we can consider the left shift $f(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(x_2, \dots)$ on the Hilbert space $l^2$. Right shift $g(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(0, x_1, x_2, \dots)$ is a right inverse of $f$.

**2.**

After you find a better formulation of your question, you may consult the main result or Lemma 3.2
of [Lawson's work](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X20300755).

If the reformulation would be similar to that in the answer of @user31373
(both variants),
it seems to me that Lawson's paper provides a sufficient extra condition that would read ``the inverse is locally Lipschitz''

**3.**
In the above, I assumed that the expression $f(g(x))=x$ (may be with a smooth function $g$, or just continuous) defines what you mean by ``locally [not] invertible''. Putting my assumption aside, let me assume that you ask whether:

- $f$ having an inverse function (locally) that is defined in a neighbourhood of $f(x)$ **and** smooth implies that $Df(x)$ is invertible?

Then the answer is positive by the chain rule (as in @Alex Becker's answer).
(We always assume $f$ is continuously differentiable.)

**4.**
For the sake of completeness, in case the question would be that

- $f$ having an inverse function (without any smoothness requirement) implies that $Df(x)$ is invertible?

then function $f(x)=x^3$ (which already appeared on this page) gives the negative answer.

**References:**
*Lawson, Jimmie*, [**An inverse function theorem converse**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.123913), J. Math. Anal. Appl. 486, No. 2, Article ID 123913, 5 p. (2020). [ZBL1456.46067](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1456.46067).